# Check whether x dates from one list are within y days of any single date from another list in R dataframe

Tags: r

Suppose we have two columns in a dataframe. Both columns contain lists of dates. The number of dates in any given cell is not fixed (i.e., can vary), as illustrated below:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(41)

randomDate <- function(date1, date2, n){
  sample(seq(as.Date(date1), as.Date(date2), by="day"), n)
}

df <- data.frame(dates1 = I(map(sample(1:25, 1000, replace=T),
                              randomDate,
                              date1="1999/01/01",
                              date2="2000/01/01")),
                 dates2 = I(map(sample(1:10, 1000, replace=T),
                              randomDate,
                              date1="1999/01/01",
                              date2="2000/01/01")))
```

To further clarify, in this reproducible example, the first observation (i.e., row 1) has 8 dates for the `dates1` variable and 2 dates for the `dates2` variable. The second observation contains 3 dates for the `dates1` variable and 9 dates for the `dates2` variable.

My goal is as follows:

> For each observation (row), check whether the observation has at least **x** dates in `dates2` within **y** days of any single date from `dates1` and return a logical (`TRUE`/`FALSE`)

For example, if we consider **x=2** and **y=14** for an observation where:

*dates1: 1999/01/05,1999/02/05*

*dates2: 1999/01/02,1999/01/30,1999/07/02,1999/02/09,1999/07/02*

I would want to return `TRUE` since 1999/01/30 and 1999/02/09 are both within 14 days of 1999/02/05.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one base R approach where we write a function to find out if there is atleast one date which has atleast `x` entries within `y` days.

```
if_any_date <- function(date1, date2, x, y) {
   if (length(date1) > 1 & length(date2) > 1)
     any(colSums(sapply(date1, function(p) abs(p - date2) < y)) >= x)  
   else 
     sum(abs(date1 - date2) < y) >= x 
}
```

We use `mapply` to apply this for every `dates1` and `dates2` combination.

```
df$result <- mapply(if_any_date, df$dates1, df$dates2, x = 2, y = 14)

head(df, 10)
#         dates1       dates2 result
#1  1999-07-.... 1999-05-....  FALSE
#2  1999-12-.... 1999-03-....  FALSE
#3  1999-09-.... 1999-01-....  FALSE
#4  1999-02-.... 1999-03-....  FALSE
#5  1999-10-....   1999-05-30  FALSE
#6  1999-05-.... 1999-12-....  FALSE
#7  1999-11-.... 1999-03-....  FALSE
#8  1999-11-....   1999-10-25  FALSE
#9  1999-02-.... 1999-02-....   TRUE
#10 1999-12-.... 1999-10-....  FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you, this is quite close. The only thing is that sum(abs(date1 - date2) < y) >= x will also evaluate to TRUE if there are x dates from dates1 within y days of a single dates2. Quick fix is just to add another if condition.

Comment: @JonS yes, I think that is an easy solution as well.